# Facebook message from an app doesn't appear fully in the timeline

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I have a question regarding posting a message from an iOS app to the Facebook timeline. When I posted a message before I could see full text of my message on my timeline - http://qblx.co/WIHuaN. But not I can see only first two lines of it  - http://qblx.co/TWIQjY. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Any information will be highly appreciated.